# Retrieve user entered data in fragment from views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am moving from frag1 to frag2, in frag1 I have 2 edit texts for first name and last name. I am also validating before going to frag2. But regardless of entering data in edit text it shows me "" value for both the edit texts. Here is the code...

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_1st_new,container,false);
    fname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_firstname);
    lname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_lastname);
    firstName = fname.getText().toString();
    lastName = lname.getText().toString();

    next1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next1);

    next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting data in first-name and last name ?

Comment: edited.. I have this in code but while posting I guess deleted by mistake..

Comment: You have to edit it as per my answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'onClick()' method first you should set data to 'firstName' and 'lastName' like

'first-name= fName.getText ().toString ()' and same for last name

Comment: sorry I already have this in my code still not working... I might have by mistake while posting here deleted this line otherwise in my code its there..

Comment: Are you setting both firstName and lastName in onClick method ?

Comment: As I said you should set in onClick method not outside it

Comment: See when you set it in 'onCreateView ()' method, initially the 'EditText' are empty so, and when you set the same in 'onClick()' method you get whatever text that is there in 'EditText'

Comment: Great sir thank u it worked... See this silly mistakes make me feel stupid... Thank u for ur guidance..

Comment: Mark it as correct if it helped to clear the unanswered queue

Answer (score 0):

```
 next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Add these two lines on your onClick
            firstName = fname.getText().toString();
            lastName = lname.getText().toString();

            if(firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```